# Are $E_i A_j + E_j A_i$ components of a tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, tensor-calculus

I want to know whether the quantities $E_i A_j + E_j A_i$ are components of a tensor? Here, $E_i$ are the components of the electric field from a particle with charge $q$ (at rest in the frame I am working), and $A_j$ are the components of the vector potential (not the four-potential) due to an arbitrary external electromagnetic field.

This term popped out (actually the gradient of this term) while I was calculating the momentum density of EM fields. Specifically, I was looking at the momentum density in the interaction between an external EM field with the electric field generated by the charged particle. I was told the term in the title was a component of a tensor, but I don't buy it. After all, the electric field itself isn't a proper tensor, but rather a piece of the electromagnetic field strength tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your remark about the electric field not being a tensor itself, I presume you are referring to Lorentz tensors (rather than tensors in three-dimensional space).  The quantities $E_{i}A_{j}$ are indeed components of a Lorentz tensor, the three-index tensor $F_{\mu\nu}A_{\rho}$.  What may be confusing you is that $E_{i}A_{j}$ is not the most general element of this tensor; they are only the components in which one of the indices is 0 (temporal) and another is 1, 2, or 3 (spatial),
$$E_{i}A_{j}=F_{0i}A_{j}.$$
So if you transform this to another frame, you will not just have a combination of the $E_{i}A_{j}$ products that you started with.  The Lorentz transformation will mix in $E_{i}A_{0}$, $B_{i}A_{j}$, and $B_{i}A_{0}$ terms.

However, the fact that your expression is not Lorentz covariant does not mean that it is wrong.  If you have specified a specific source $j_{\mu}$, you will not expect to get a covariant expression—because the $j_{\mu}$ source is not itself covariant.  Since your source contains a point charge at rest (for which $j_{\mu}=0$ unless $\mu=0$), you should expect to get quantities that have one Lorentz index fixed to 0 to match.